# Replace dot in between slash i.e. '/./' with single slash '/'

Tags: java, regex, replace

For this string `dirPath`,

```
String dirPath = "c:/create/a/dir/very/deep/inside/../././../../../dir/";
```

I want the output string to look like :

```
"c:/create/a/dir/very/deep/inside/../../../../dir/";
```

I used :

```
dirPath.replaceAll("/[.]/", "/");
```

but that gave :

```
c:/create/a/dir/very/deep/inside/.././../../../dir/
                                   ^^^
```

then, tried with one more `replaceAll` as:

```
dirPath.replaceAll("/[.]/", "/").replaceAll("/[.]/", "/");
```

and that worked!

My question is why couldn't one call achieve the same result? 
How to achieve it in simplest way?

P.S. Another regex that didn't work for me : `.replaceAll("($|/)[.]/", "$1")`

Comment: I don't know if there is a one liner way to do, but one solution might to loop while the `String` contains `/./` and continue to replace its occurrence :/

Comment: IMO, using loop will be overkill for this simple yet general task.

Comment: Never said it was a good idea, just didn't have a better solution ;)

Comment: Why do you need to remove the dots, but not normalize for the dot dots? Surely if whatever you are passing this string to can handle both or neither?

Comment: I am passing this converted string to Java glob path matcher, which matches it against literal dots. That's why conversion is absolutely necessary. Read more here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob

Comment: @AndyTurner Good suggestion. Eventually I found out that using `File.getCanonicalPath()` over the string path made the job really simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lookahead pattern to avoid consuming the slash needed by the subsequent match:

```
dirPath.replaceAll("/\\.(?=/)", "")
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qWKVU3/1 or http://tpcg.io/ijmYJF

Comment: Works really well. Thanks. Any good reference to learn about this look-ahead pattern?

Comment: Should we prefer `\\.` over `[.]` to match a single dot? Some recommends the later one i.e. `[.]` with brackets.

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can learn more about lookahead and lookbehind patterns [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). I personally prefer escaping dots with backslashes because square brackets are really meant to include two or more characters.

Comment: Thus wouldn't strip `/.` at the end of the string. Don't know if that is important to OP.